# Apache: Send pre-packed gzip'ed files

Tags: apache-2.2, cache, gzip, rewrite

I want Apache to send static files gzip'ed over the wire, but also want Apache to not always gzip them over and over again. So I thought if it wouldn't be possible to deliver an .gz file if it exists. This set-up:

File structure:

```
static/
|
|--- style.css
|
\--- style.css.gz
```

And the following in an .htaccess:

mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -s
RewriteRule ^(.+) $1.gz [L]
```

And this setting:

```
AddEncoding x-gzip .gz
```

Actually, this works insofar as the .gz file is sent instead of the .css, if the request goes to `/static/style.css`. The problem is only, that the file is delivered as "application/x-gzip" and not as "text/css". Using mod_rewrite's T flag doesn't alter this. Neither does an explicit

```
AddType text/css .css
```

Has anyone an idea, how I could achieve the desired behaviour? Or is it unnecessary for some reason I didn't reckon?

**EDIT:** There is an additional difficulty: Sending the original file to clients without gzip support. Has anyone an idea how this could work?

Comment: I'm amazed this isn't way more obvious, as it seems crazy to have a web server that doesn't do this. I think IIS has a system to cache gzipped copies of static files on first access. mod_deflate doesn't mention such a feature.

Comment: apache's mod_deflate docs have their own example now: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html#precompressed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution for sending the correct version to browsers that don't accept gzip would be something along the lines of:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} !gzip
...your rules here...
```

Also, there is another way to change the type, namely:

```
<FilesMatch .*\.css.gz>
    ForceType text/css
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch .*\.js.gz>
    ForceType text/javascript
</FilesMatch>
```

HTH.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Are there docs for the %{HTTP:...} thingy? I didn't see any mentioning of it in the RewriteCond section of Apache 2.2. The FilesMatch was another idea I had but I thought it more verbose. Since both rules need to fire up the regexp engine, there should be no real difference.

Comment: OK, found the docs. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html I just skipped the interesting part.

Comment: This isn't a huge problem, but reading that config, if someone manually fetched the .css.gz file, they would get the text/css, when they should get the application/x-gzip type.

Comment: Why the ! before gzip on the Accept-Encoding line? Surely that's the opposite of what you need?

Comment: I was thinking the same, it makes sense to have the `RewriteCond` only match when the client _does_ accept gzip encoding.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, it seems I found a solution: The T flag does not work if set on the same rule, but it sure does, if you spend it a rule of its own:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -s
RewriteRule ^(.+) $1.gz

RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css]
RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript]
```

Still I would like to hear others' solutions and opinions.